# Glade Textview doesn't display text

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm writing a c program using codeblocks and glade. At first I thought the problem was because of my code. I tried sample code that I found online that doesn't use glade - GTK only - and it worked. Then I tried a new glade with only a window and a textview but it didn't work as well.

```
GtkTextBuffer *buffer= gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview1));
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffer, &iter, 0);
gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, "Plain text ... it's working\n", -1);

//gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "Hello, this is some text", -1);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
```

I also tried the commented line. So the question is how to make glade textviews display text.

Worth mentioning as well that hard coded text that I put using glade itself didn't appear.
Here is the full code.

```
GtkWidget *textview1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkBuilder      *builder;
GtkWidget       *window;
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
GtkTextIter iter;

builder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Unsaved 1.glade", NULL);

window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

g_object_unref(builder);
textview1=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "textview1"));



GtkTextBuffer *buffer= gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview1));
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffer, &iter, 0);
gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, "Plain text ... it's working\n", -1);
gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "Hello, this is some text", -1);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
struct Student_t* arrayOfStudents=load();
return 0;
}
```

glade file :

```
    <interface>
<requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
<!--  interface-naming-policy project-wide  -->
<object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
<property name="window_position">center</property>
<property name="default_width">1000</property>
<property name="default_height">600</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
<property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="orientation">vertical</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-add</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
<property name="image_position">top</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-refresh</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button3">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-find</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button4">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Statistics</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_underline">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">3</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button5">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Normalize</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="xalign">0.44999998807907104</property>
<property name="yalign">0.44999998807907104</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">4</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button10">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-edit</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">5</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox3">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button6">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-open</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button7">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-save</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button8">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-delete</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button11">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Raise HL</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">3</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button9">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-quit</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">4</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="buffer">textbuffer1</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkStatusbar" id="statusbar1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="spacing">2</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Mazen Sharkawy</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Shorouk Assem</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="position">3</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
</child>
</object>
</child>
</object>
<object class="GtkDialog" id="dialog1">
<property name="border_width">5</property>
<property name="type_hint">normal</property>
<property name="has_separator">False</property>
<child internal-child="vbox">
<object class="GtkVBox" id="dialog-vbox1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="orientation">vertical</property>
<property name="spacing">2</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="orientation">vertical</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">ID</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Name</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry2">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox3">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label3">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">GPA</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry3">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">2</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox4">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label4">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">E-mail</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry4">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">3</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox6">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label5">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Mobile</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry5">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">4</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox7">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label6">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">Age</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry6">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">5</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox8">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkLabel" id="label7">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="label" translatable="yes">City</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry7">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="invisible_char">●</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">6</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child internal-child="action_area">
<object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="dialog-action_area1">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="layout_style">end</property>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-cancel</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">False</property>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">gtk-save</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_stock">True</property>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="fill">False</property>
<property name="position">1</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
<packing>
<property name="expand">False</property>
<property name="pack_type">end</property>
<property name="position">0</property>
</packing>
</child>
</object>
</child>
<action-widgets>
<action-widget response="0">button2</action-widget>
<action-widget response="0">button1</action-widget>
</action-widgets>
</object>
<object class="GtkTextBuffer" id="textbuffer1">
<property name="text" translatable="yes">shit happens</property>
</object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Please show more code. Nothing is wrong with the snippet you posted; the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @andlabs I added the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `g_object_unref(builder);`, you are saying that you have no intention of using `builder` anymore. It is similar to saying `free(builder)`, except that it uses GObject's reference counting, which is more complicated and outside the scope of this answer. The point is: you're still trying to use `builder` after calling `g_object_unref()`, and that *will* fail. And in your case, it does, so the `textview1` variable never gets a reference to your text view, so the GtkTextBuffer operations don't work. Remove the `g_object_unref()` line from your code, and everything should work.

Comment: I did remove it but the problem persists. Nothing changed.

Comment: Added the glade file

Comment: it certainly has. Here : ` <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1"> `